# Elasticsearch count overlapping timeranges in date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

I have events stored in Elasticsearch 6.6 that have a start and end time e.g.:

```
{
  "startTime": "2019-01-11T14:49:16.719Z"
  "endTime": "2019-01-11T16:31:56.483Z"
}
```

I want to display a date histogram which shows the number of overlapping events in each hour.

Example:

```
Hour of Day:
12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19

Events:
   <====E1====>    <===E2==>
            <===E3====>
           <==E4==>
Result:
 0   1   1   3   2   2   1   0
```

Is there a way to do this with an elasticsearch aggregation or do I have to implement it in the application?

Comment: are you using KIBANA?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti no. I have it installed, but I need the data in my application.